# Розквітнуть чи розквітнуться? Чи є різниця?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, вибір-слова

Нещодавно трапився віршик дитячий:

> Ген, струмок веде свою
>   Пісеньку в долині
>   Скоро проліски в гаю
>   Розквітнуться сині!

Як на мене, очевидно це переклад рос. вірша,і мені здається більше правильно було б написати "Розквітнуть..."

Comment: Цікаво що [slovnyk.ua](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F) містить таку форму, але це дійсно схоже на автоматичний переклад слова "расцветутся" - "будуть інтенсивно розквітати".

Answer (score 3):

На сайті Словник зустрічаємо як [перше](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8), так і [друге](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F) слово. Однак слова "розквітнутися" немає в СУМі (але там є слово [розквітнути](http://sum.in.ua/s/rozkvitnuty)), немає його і в [Словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8). Та й в Інтернеті немає ніяких доказів того, щоб це слово вживалося ще десь окрім цього дитячого віршика, тому я гадаю, що не варто його використовувати.

Також хочу поставити під сумнів, що це автоматичний переклад слова "расцветутся", бо, наприклад, Гугл його перекладає як: "розквітнуть" або "розцвітуть". Можливо, це просто помилка перекладача.